# How to add load event of dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add load event in all the elements that are dynamically added any time of the page.

I am trying to set the load event of all the tabindex property element, like this but not working.

```
    $('body').on('load','[tabindex]',function(event){
      alert();
});
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I doubt, `DOMElement` has `load` `event`..